# Compare two fields from different arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I hope somebody could help me with topic...
I have a mongoDB query based in a "Tickets, Tasks and Comentaries(Coms)" sctructure, Tickets array usually contains Tasks array and Coms array, so I need to unwind them. my code is:

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$Coms" },
    {$match:{
        'Tsks.Sts': 'Closed', //Status: tasks which are closed
        'Coms.TicTskId': {$eq: '$Tsks._id'},**
        'Coms.Typ':'CloseTask'

        }},

    {$project:{
        _id:0,
        'Tsks._id':1,
        'Tsks.Sts':1,
        'Tsks.DueDat':1,
        'Nms.Org':1,
        'Nms.Cmp':1,
        'Nms.Wkg':1,    
        'Coms.Typ':1,
        'Coms.Msg': 1,
        'Coms.TicTskId':1
        }},

    {$unwind : "$Tsks" },
    {$match:{$and:[{
        'Tsks.Sts': 'Closed',
        'Tsks.DueDat': {$ne: null},
        'Tsks._id':{$gt:0}
        }]}},

    {$group:
        {_id:{Org:'$Nms.Org',Cmp:'$Nms.Cmp',Wkg:'$Nms.Wkg', DueDate:'$Tsks.DueDat', CurTskId: '$Tsks._id',Type:'$Coms.Typ',Msg: '$Coms.Msg', TicTskId: '$Coms.TicTskId'},
        Total_Closed:{$sum:1},
        }},

    {$project:{
        Total_Closed : 1,
        Comparation: {$cmp: [ '$CurTskId', '$TicTskId']},
        Equal: {$eq: [ "$CurTskId", "$TicTskId"]},
        }},
        { 
             $sort : {CurEntNme:-1,Org: 1,Cmp : 1 ,Wkg: 1 } 
          }

     ])
```

I'm trying to show a group of tasks which need to follow those characteristics:

```
    "Sts":"Closed", --> Status should be Closed
    'Tsks.DueDat': {$ne: null}, --> Tasks DueDate shouldn't be null
    'Coms.Typ':'CloseTask', --> Coments type should be "CloseTask"
    'Coms.TicTskId' == '$Tsks._id' --> Comments ID should be as same as Tasks ID
```

My principal issue here is that I can't find the way to get ONLY values with all of these grouping conditions, I mean, I cann see all the conditions EXCEPT the last one, when both ID's are equals. I wan to see only all which are iqual, but This query is returning both, independently if they're equal or not. For example, one result I get:

```
result:
  [item]
     _id:
       Org--> Organization
       Company --> Organization 1
       Wkg --> WKG 1
       DueDate --> 2015-04-10 15:00:00.000Z
       CurTskId --> 7
       Type --> CloseTask
       Msg --> these is close
       TicTskId --> 1
   Total_Closed --> 1
   Comparation --> 0 
   Equal --> true
```

> Comparation shouldn't be 0 because CurTskId and TicTskId aren't
>   similar
>
> Equal shouldn't be true because CurTskId and TicTskId aren't similar

One Ticket database structure looks like:

```
>(1) 12000000        {7 fields}          Object
    _id              12000000             Int64
    TicId            1001                 Int32
    OrgId            2                    Int32
    Sts              Closed               String
   >Nms              {3 fields}           Object
    Cmp              Organization 1       String
    Org              Organization         String
    Wkg              Workgroup            String
  >Tsks              {3 fields}           Object
    _id              1                    Int32
    Sts              Closed               String
    DueDat           2015-04-10           Date
  >Coms              {3 fields}           Object
   TicTskId          7                    Int32
   Typ               CloseTask            String
   Msg               these is close       String
```

I hope I have explain in the best way my problem, and sorry if my english is not very good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please try to include the actual code in your question instead of images because code in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem. Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers. You're asking us to volunteer our time for free to solve your problem, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Comment: Hi chridam, sorry for the images, I have edit my post trying to explain my issue as best as I can without uploading any image in a third site. I have an specific corporative database which I can't share, so I hope somebody will be able to understand my problem, I have been investigating this issue since many weeks ago. Thanks for your comment and kind regards.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to update the question. I understand you have a specific corporate database which you can't share but could you possibly update your question with some a sample test set of documents with test data and the expected aggregation result that we can possibly replicate, test and provide a solution or suggestions? As it is, it's a bit hard to follow without some test data to pay around with.

Comment: From your update, the following fields `Nms`, `Tsks` and `Coms` are displayed as `Objects` but in the beginning of your question you mention that they are arrays? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I just considered them like "Arrays" because they have different id's and components inside them, but they're Objects in the database, when I put a > at the beginning of Nms, Tsks, Coms, I mean that in robomongo I can drilldown this objects and I have new items inside them. For this reason I need to unwind them in the query to reach this items and my principal problem is how to compare two items inside two differents Objects (Coms.id = Tasks.id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data you have in your question, suppose you have the following document schema and data:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 12000000,
    "TicId" : 1001,
    "OrgId" : 2,
    "Sts" : "Closed",
    "Nms" : [ 
        {
            "Cmp" : "Organization 1",
            "Org" : "Organization",
            "Wkg" : "Workgroup"
        }
    ],
    "Tsks" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "Sts" : "Closed",
            "DueDat" : ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "Coms" : [ 
        {
            "TicTskId" : 1,
            "Typ" : "CloseTask",
            "Msg" : "these is close"
        }
    ]
}
```

To make an aggregation that compares two fields in the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline is not possible, however a workaround is to set the condition while storing the data in an additional field in your pipeline through a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) operation so that you can do a quick truth check with the `isComsTsksEqual` field. It would be super fast to do that type of query. As you can see in the above test document, `"Tsks._id"` is equal to "Coms.TicTskId" thus the additional `isComsTsksEqual` field becomes true,  and you can use that in your [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator now. The following aggregation pipeline demonstrates this:

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "TicId": 1,
            "OrgId": 1,
            "Sts": 1,
            "Nms": 1,
            "Tsks": 1,
            "Coms": 1,
            "TsksComp": "$Tsks._id"            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "TicId": 1,
            "OrgId": 1,
            "Sts": 1,
            "Nms": 1,
            "Tsks": 1,
            "Coms": 1, 
            "isComsTsksEqual": { 
                "$eq" : [ "$Coms.TicTskId", "$TsksComp" ] 
            }
        }
    },  
    {
        "$unwind": "$Tsks"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$Coms" 
    },    
    {
        "$match": {
            "Tsks.Sts": "Closed",             
            "Coms.Typ": "CloseTask",
            "isComsTsksEqual": true
        }
    }
]);
```

This will return

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 12000000,
            "TicId" : 1001,
            "OrgId" : 2,
            "Sts" : "Closed",
            "Nms" : [ 
                {
                    "Cmp" : "Organization 1",
                    "Org" : "Organization",
                    "Wkg" : "Workgroup"
                }
            ],
            "Tsks" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Sts" : "Closed",
                "DueDat" : ISODate("2015-04-10T00:00:00.000Z")
            },
            "Coms" : {
                "TicTskId" : 1,
                "Typ" : "CloseTask",
                "Msg" : "these is close"
            },
            "isComsTsksEqual" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Not certain about what your objective is with the aggregation but you can then  modify your current aggregation pipeline by integrating the above:

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "TicId": 1,
            "OrgId": 1,
            "Sts": 1,
            "Nms": 1,
            "Tsks": 1,
            "Coms": 1,
            "TsksComp": "$Tsks._id"            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "TicId": 1,
            "OrgId": 1,
            "Sts": 1,
            "Nms": 1,
            "Tsks": 1,
            "Coms": 1, 
            "isComsTsksEqual": { 
                "$eq" : [ "$Coms.TicTskId", "$TsksComp" ] 
            }
        }
    },  
    {
        "$unwind": "$Tsks"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$Coms" 
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": "$Nms" 
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "Tsks.Sts": "Closed",             
            "Coms.Typ": "CloseTask",
            "Tsks._id": { "$gt": 0 },
            "Tsks.Sts": "Closed",
            "Tsks.DueDat": { "$ne": null },
            "isComsTsksEqual": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "Org": "$Nms.Org",
                "Cmp": "$Nms.Cmp",
                "Wkg": "$Nms.Wkg", 
                "DueDate": "$Tsks.DueDat", 
                "CurEntNme": "$OpnPrps.CurEntNme", 
                "CurTskId": "$Tsks._id",
                "Type": "$Coms.Typ",
                "Msg": "$Coms.Msg", 
                "TicTskId": "$Coms.TicTskId"
            },
            "Total_Closed": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }/*,
    {
        "$project": {
            "Total_Closed": 1,
            "Comparison": { 
                "$cmp": [ "$CurTskId", "$TicTskId" ]
            },
            "Equal": {
                "$eq": [ "$CurTskId", "$TicTskId" ]
            },
        }
    }*/,
    { 
        "$sort": {
            "CurEntNme": -1,
            "Org": 1,
            "Cmp": 1,
            "Wkg": 1 
        } 
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much chridam! Finally the "double project structure" works fine and now I only get results with same tasks and Coms ID. I get less results as I expected but this is another thing I need to investigate. Thank you again for your time :)